# Running argparse with optional arguments that won't require specifying output filename

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, optional-arguments

I have read through a bunch of the questions already answered, but I don't see this covered--at least not that I recognized.

I am using argparse to take a file and convert it to a different type. The input filename is required. The output filename is NOT required as the optional argument should handle that. Here is the code so far:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert file to new type')
parser.add_argument('--json', type=str, help='Converts to json format')
parser.add_argument('--bibtex', type=str, help='Converts to bibtex format')
parser.add_argument('--html', type=str, help='Converts to html format')
parser.add_argument('inputfilename', type=str, help='enter the original filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
filename=args.filename
if args.json:
    print('Converting to json ...')
    #conversion code here
elif args.bibtex:
    print('Converting to bibtex ...')
    #conversion code here
elif args.html:
    print('Converting to html ...')
    #conversion code here
else:
    print('No conversion type indicated')
```

The problem is that whenever I use one of these flags. If I do

```
$ ./orsconvert.py --json inputfilename
```

I get an error saying

```
orsconvert.py: error: the following arguments are required: inputfilename
```

It does this because it interprets the provided `inputfilename` as an outputfilename connected to the `--json`. It is trying to force me to actually state the output filename after the optional argument and before the input filename, similar to this:

```
$ ./orsconvert.py --json outputfilename inputfileneame
```

However, I do not want to do that if there is a way around it. I want it to accept `--json` as the indication of what to do and then use `inputfilename` as the input and automatically save it as `outputfilename` according to what the code will specify.

Yes, I am looking at making the 3 optional arguments a group to simplify the code ... but that still doesn't explain how to get it to not require another argument after the optional one and before the final `inputfilename` required argument.

Is there something else I can put in the `parser.add_argument('...')` field that will stop requiring me to specify an `outputfilename`? I would like to change the code as little as possible because I am already pushing the limits of my coding comprehension.

Comment: I'm not sure that setup is sound. It seems to me that what you actually want are 1-2 file names and a "mode", instead of 1 filename, a "mode" and an optional "mode-filename". That should be a choice/subparser for the mode, a positional filename and a `nargs="?"` filename.

Comment: Can't you have the optional outputfilename as its own argument, and boolean flags for the type (ignoring what should happen if more than one type is specified)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `--json` to require an argument, and it's taking the input file name as that argument. Your three converters should use the `store_true` action, not the default `store` action.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert file to new type')
parser.add_argument('--json', action='store_true', help='Converts to json format')
parser.add_argument('--bibtex', action='store_true', help='Converts to bibtex format')
parser.add_argument('--html', action='store_true', help='Converts to html format')
parser.add_argument('inputfilename', help='enter the original filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

With this change, `args.json` et all are the Boolean values you expect them to be. The `store_true` action takes care of defining the type to be `bool` and the default value to be `false`.

---

Better yet, though, would be a single required positional argument that must take the value `json`, `bibtex`, or `html`. Then `parse_args` itself would detect if an incorrect or missing conversion type was given.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert file to new type')
parser.add_argument('inputfilename', help='enter the original filename')
parser.add_argument('conversion_type', choices=['json', 'bibtex', 'html'])
args = parser.parse_args()
filename = args.filename
conversion_type = args.conversion_type  # Guaranteed to be json, html, or bibtex
if conversion_type == "json":
    ...
elif conversion_type == "bibtex":
    ...
elif conversion_type == "html":
```

---

If you would like an option with a *default* value, buckle up :) We're going to add *4* options: one that lets specify the output type explicitly, and three shortcuts for setting it.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('inputfilename')
p.add_argument('--type', choices=['json', 'bibtex', 'html'], default='json')
p.add_argument('--json', action='store_const', const='json', dest='type')
p.add_argument('--html', action='store_const', const='html', dest='type')
p.add_argument('--bibtex', action='store_const', const='bibtex', dest='type')
```

`--json`, `--bibtex`, and `--html` have the same effect as `--type json`, `--type bibtex`, and `--type html`, respectively. As before, `--type` can only take those three values as its argument. If more than one of these, the last one used takes effect.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. I did not realize that making a variable optional with -- by default makes it require another argument.

Comment: Only by default :) Let's take a step back. Prefixing the argument name with `--` makes it an option, rather than a positional argument. Each option has an associated *action*, though, which is `'store'` by default. It's the store action that makes the option require an argument if the option is used. `'store_const'`, on the other hand, does *not* require an argument, because you are providing the value to store upfront in the argument definition.

Comment: Okay, so from a practical perspective, why would I want to use 'store_true' vs why would I want to use 'store_const'? I like the 'choices=[...]' idea, but my supervisor wants me to keep the fields with hyphens '--json', '--bibtex', '--html' even though at least one is required.

Comment: `store_true` is basically a special case of `store_const`. `add_argument("...", action='store_true')` is short for `add_argument("...", action='store_const', const=True, type=bool, default=False)`. (There is a corresponding `store_false` action as well.)

Comment: You might want to look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion as well, which can ensure that exactly one of the three options is chosen, just like `choices` for a single option or argument.

Comment: I actually had just incorporated 'parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()' to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` already ships with everything you need to actually have the API you want, not the one you think you need.

- The type should be one of several `choices`, not three separate flags.
- The `inputfilename` should be required.
- The `outputfilename` should be optional.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert file to new type')
parser.add_argument('format', choices=["json", "bibtex", "html"])
parser.add_argument('inputfilename', type=str)
parser.add_argument('outputfilename', type=str, nargs="?")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

This automatically provides the desired usage, without misusing optionals but gaining error handling instead.

```sh
$ ./converter json in.txt
Namespace(format='json', inputfilename='in.txt', outputfilename=None)
$ ./converter html in.txt out.html
Namespace(format='html', inputfilename='in.txt', outputfilename='out.html')
$ ./converter yaml in.txt         
usage: converter [-h] {json,bibtex,html} inputfilename [outputfilename]
converter: error: argument format: invalid choice: 'yaml' (choose from 'json', 'bibtex', 'html')
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to steal your answer; I think it appeared while I was adding this same suggestion.

Comment: @chepner At least we did not pick the same order of arguments. ;)

Comment: I *am* tempted to steal that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that argparse is expecting an input, especially since you have `type=str`

Try replacing the json arg with this instead

```
parser.add_argument('--json', action="store_true", help='Converts to json format')
```

Answer (score -2):

So the problem seems as if every argparse.arg requires an argument to be specified, be it anything. So you could set it to a boolean maybe. But I think maybe this approach could be better:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert file to new type')
parser.add_argument('--type', type=str, help='Converts to any of the following formats: 1 for json, 2 for bibtex and 3 for html')
parser.add_argument('--inputfilename', type=str, help='enter the original filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
filename=args.inputfilename
if args.type:
    conversion_type = int(args.type)
    if conversion_type == int(1):
        print('Converting to json ...')
        #conversion code here
    elif conversion_type == 2:
        print('Converting to bibtex ...')
        #conversion code here
    elif conversion_type == 3:
        print('Converting to html ...')
        #conversion code here
else:
    print('No conversion type indicated')
```

Just add an arg for specifying the type. Based on that, convert or dont as per the conditionals.

Comment: I don't think ``type`` and ``inputfilename`` should be *optional*. Argparse already supports choices, so having some opaque numbering scheme (that messes with types badly) isn't really appropriate either.

Comment: Guess I didn't know about the `action=store_true` option. Apologies if my answer was misleading.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I guess that's true